# Inverting a FlatList

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on a react native app for android, and have access to the new FlatList. It has some very needed features. However, my listview is inverted using the react-native-invertable-scroll-view. This does not seem to work properly with FlatList. The scrolling is not properly reversed.

Does anyone know how to invert a FlatList? Or perhaps how to load a Flatlist, and then force a scroll to the bottom without the user noticing it? My own attempts to force a scroll down are often delayed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
render() {
const messages = this.props.messages.reverse();

return (
  <FlatList
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    data={ messages }
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    style={{  transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }] }}
  />
); }

_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id+''+index;

_renderItem = ({item}) => (
<View style={{ transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }]}}>
  <ChatItem />
</View>)
```

Enjoy it)

Comment: Worked! Thanks Богдан :-)

Comment: I was wondering if you have had any comments on this with Android functionality? We are using this in our production chat and the list is not working on the Huwaii Honor 8 phone, but most others it is fine.

Comment: Note above, you should call `this.props.messages.slice().reverse()` because `.reverse()` will modify the list in places, causing issues with state, redux, etc.

Comment: this worked, but I think , this is a bad practice while need fetch more data to list

Comment: this is magic!! Solves so many problems for me. Also you don't need to reverse() data if its already in proper format.

Answer (score 92):

This now comes out of the box in FlatList!

Just use:

```
<FlatList
  inverted
  data=...
  renderItem=...
/>
```

This causes the first item to appear at the bottom of the list, and the list starts at the bottom, showing the first item.

If you need the last item to show at the bottom, just reverse the array that you are providing in the `data` prop.

Comment: thanks a lot I can rtl my horizontal list with your suggest . thanks

Comment: this will cause a terrible user experience

Comment: Not at all, it depends what you want to do. If you're building a chat app, then this makes sense

Answer (score -3):

As described in the other answers, currently the best way to go about doing this is to apply a transformation to the FlatList's containing view that inverts it.

```
return (
    <View style={{ transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }] }} >
        <FlatList
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            ...
        />
    </View>
);
```

Then apply the same transformation to each list item to ensure that they are correctly reoriented.

```
_renderItem = (info) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }] }}>
            {this.props.renderItem(info)}
        </View>
    );
}
```

I've written a package that does exactly that, all you need to do is use this in place of a standard `FlatList` component and pass the `inverted` property.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-invertible-flat-list

Comment: any ideas on how to invert also the pull-to-refresh along with the content? in a chat application you need to load earlier messages at the top. With this solution, FlatList's onRefresh will add the RefreshControl at the bottom.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16424795)

Comment: @mitelone are you positive of this? I've been using this in my own application, haven't tested thoroughly but on brief inspection it looks like the RefreshControl is at the top.

If this is indeed the case that it gets added to the bottom I don't have any great ideas on how to flip it. I'll think on it after some testing.

Comment: @BrunoPeres thanks for the tip, answer edited to include information regarding the technical details of the fix.